# Submit form values to external URL shown displayed an iframe

Tags: javascript, url, forms

I am trying to make a form that on submit passes values to a external URL and show the results as an iframe. The form is the home page and the results must be shown in the first page as well.

Everery time I submit it returns a 404 error.

Here is the code:

```
<form id="buscaAereo" method="POST" name="formularioAereo" action="<?php echo home_url('/' ); ?>">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="half">
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="idaevolta" id="idaevolta" value="1" checked>
                Ida e Volta
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="half">
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="idaevolta" id="idaevolta" value="2" checked>
                So ida
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="half">
            <label for="name">Origem:</label>
            <input type="text" class="cidade" name="origem" data-provide="typeahead">
        </div>
        <div class="half">
            <label for="name">Destino:</label>
            <input type="text" id="cidade" name="destino" data-provide="typeahead">
        </div>

        <div class="half">
            <label for="name">Data de ida:</label>
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                <input class="sapn1" id="date" name="ida" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="half">
            <label for="name">Data de volta:</label>
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                <input class="" id="date" name="volta" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="quarter">
            <label for="country">Adultos:</label>
            <select id="country" name="adultos">
                <option value="0">00</option>
                <option value="1" selected="selected">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
                <option value="3">03</option>
                <option value="4">04</option>
                <option value="5">05</option>
                <option value="6">06</option>
                <option value="7">07</option>
                <option value="8">08</option>
                <option value="9">09</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="quarter">
            <label for="country">Criancas:</label>
            <select id="country" name="criancas">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">00</option>
                <option value="1">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
                <option value="3">03</option>
                <option value="4">04</option>
                <option value="5">05</option>
                <option value="6">06</option>
                <option value="7">07</option>
                <option value="8">08</option>
                <option value="9">09</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="quarter">
            <label for="country">Bebes:</label>
            <select id="country" name="bebes">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">00</option>
                <option value="1">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
                <option value="3">03</option>
                <option value="4">04</option>
                <option value="5">05</option>
                <option value="6">06</option>
                <option value="7">07</option>
                <option value="8">08</option>
                <option value="9">09</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="quarter">
            <input type="submit" id="busca" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary botao" value="Pesquizar">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the PHP code:

```
function buscaPassagem() {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $idaevolta = $_POST["idaevolta"];
        $origem = $_POST["origem"];
        $destino = $_POST["destino"];
        $ida = $_POST["ida"];
        $volta = $_POST["volta"];
        $adultos = $_POST["adultos"];
        $criancas = $_POST["criancas"];
        $bebes = $_POST["bebes"];

        $link = "http://www.portaldoagente.com.br/OTAFrame/SuiteAerea/guiAereoAeroportos.aspx?PesquisaAutomatica=S&Tipo="; 

        $UrlFinal = $link
            .$idaevolta
            ."&Origem=".$origem
            ."&Destino=".$destino
            ."&Adultos=".$adultos
            ."&Criancas=".$criancas
            ."&Bebes=".$bebes
            ."&DataIda=".$ida
            ."&DataVolta=".$bebes
            ."&LojaChave=bG9qYXRlbXBvc3Jpbw==";

        echo "<script>window.open('$UrlFinal', 'meu_frame');</script>";
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: On plain php it works fine, but when i try to submit it returns a error. This hapenning because of wordpress..

Comment: This isn't a WordPress-specific question. Migrating to SO ...

Comment: @user2295500 Try the new code i just posted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to target the form action to your iframe. Also, that action must point your php code. (second piece of code of your question)

```
 <form target='iFrame' id="buscaAereo" method="POST" name="formularioAereo" action="your_php_code">
   ....
 </form>

 <iframe id="iFrameID" name="iFrame"></iframe>
```

**EDIT:** Try this code

**JQuery:**

```
function enviar()
{
   var link = "http://www.portaldoagente.com.br/OTAFrame/SuiteAerea/guiAereoAeroportos.aspx?PesquisaAutomatica=S&Tipo="; 

   var UrlFinal = link + $('input[name=idaevolta]:checked').val()
        +"&Origem="+$("#origem").val()
        +"&Destino="+$("#destino").val()
        +"&Criancas="+$('#criancas :selected').val()
        +"&DataIda="+$("#ida").val()
        +"&DataVolta="+$("#volta").val()
        +"&Bebes="+$('#bebes :selected').val()
        +"&Adultos="+$('#adultos :selected').val()
        +"&LojaChave=bG9qYXRlbXBvc3Jpbw==";
    $("#iFrameID").attr("src", UrlFinal);
}
```

**HTML:**

Ida e Volta

```
    <div class="half">
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="idaevolta" value="2" checked>
            So ida
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="half">
        <label for="name">Origem:</label>
        <input id="origem" type="text" class="cidade" name="origem" data-provide="typeahead">
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <label for="name">Destino:</label>
        <input type="text" id="destino" name="destino" data-provide="typeahead">
    </div>

    <div class="half">
        <label for="name">Data de ida:</label>
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            <input class="sapn1" id="ida" name="ida" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="half">
        <label for="name">Data de volta:</label>
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            <input class="" id="volta" name="volta" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quarter">
        <label for="adultos">Adultos:</label>
        <select id="adultos" name="adultos">
            <option value="0">00</option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">01</option>
            <option value="2">02</option>
            <option value="3">03</option>
            <option value="4">04</option>
            <option value="5">05</option>
            <option value="6">06</option>
            <option value="7">07</option>
            <option value="8">08</option>
            <option value="9">09</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="quarter">
        <label for="criancas">Criancas:</label>
        <select id="criancas" name="criancas">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">00</option>
            <option value="1">01</option>
            <option value="2">02</option>
            <option value="3">03</option>
            <option value="4">04</option>
            <option value="5">05</option>
            <option value="6">06</option>
            <option value="7">07</option>
            <option value="8">08</option>
            <option value="9">09</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="quarter">
        <label for="bebes">Bebes:</label>
        <select id="bebes" name="bebes">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">00</option>
            <option value="1">01</option>
            <option value="2">02</option>
            <option value="3">03</option>
            <option value="4">04</option>
            <option value="5">05</option>
            <option value="6">06</option>
            <option value="7">07</option>
            <option value="8">08</option>
            <option value="9">09</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="quarter">
        <button onClick="javascript:enviar();">Pesquizar</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<iframe id="iFrameID" name="iFrame"></iframe>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When i submit the form it loads the same page that i'm in(a copie)

Comment: So, leave action empty or a #.

Comment: Yes, it would be an option. So, you want to submit the form and open a new page with the generated link? If that is, wait for my edit in a few.

Comment: I want to submit the form and open in the same page... the results under the form.. like this site http://www.boutiquedeviagens.com.br/index.asp this is what i am trying to do... just like it.. take a look